# Issue whilst comparing instances with HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, instance

I am trying to get a value from a HashMap via a custom class I have created.

The custom class:

```
public class Coordinates {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coordinates(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public boolean isSame(Coordinates coords) {
        if (coords.getX() == this.x && coords.getY() == this.y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getAsString() {
        return "("+this.x+", "+this.y+")";
    }

    public Coordinates getCoords() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

I Have a HashMap called coordsJCB and when I try to get the JCButton (a custom swing button) it says it cannot find it.

```
private static HashMap<Coordinates, JCButton> coordsJCB = new HashMap<Coordinates, JCButton>();
coordsJCB.get(coords);
```

I did a little debugging and noticed that

```
System.out.println(new Coordinates(2, 3).equals(new Coordinates(2, 3)));
```

printed false, even though they are the same.
I googled it and got many answers about overriding the .equals function. However this will not help me as I don't want to compare 2 instances of 'Coordinates', I need to get a value from the HashMap by passing it an instance of Coordinates.

Any help much appreciated as I have absolutely no idea what to do. :/

Comment: it printed false because they are different objects because of the `new` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HashMap`'s key set hashes its elements and compares them by hash.

You need to override `Object.hashCode` and `Object.equals` in your `Coordinates` class.

Your `equals` method should return `true` when `x` and `y` equal `otherCoordinates.x` and `otherCoordinates.y` respectively.

For the `hashCode` it's a bit trickier because your hash will be based on two `int`s, so you need to find a way to avoid weak hashes (i.e. easily duplicated hashes).

Your IDE's boilerplate `hashCode` implementation functionalities should help you out there, but you can do additional bit shifting and use better prime seeds.

For instance in Ecplise:

- Right-click your `Coordinates` class
- Click `source`
- Click `Generate hashCode() and equals()...`

Comment: Thanks so much. Works like a dream :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to override hashCode() and equals() method in Coordinates Class. 
Look at how a hashMap works in Java. It will check the object equality by calling equals() method whose default implementation checks the references using "==" operator. 
That will be false in your case, so you cannot retrieve the value expected .